# How to get rid of sub lists of a list in a list in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell

I'm kinda new to Haskell and would like to know how to do the following:

```
L = [[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]]
```

How do I get rid of all the sub list (`[1,2], [1,2,3]`) and get a result of `[[1,2,3,4]]` only?

Comment: Use `isInfixOf` in `Data.List`

Comment: I tried the following, the first function works but the second one results in errors, i'm probably missing something obvious.

subList :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Bool
subList a b = if isSubsequenceOf a b then False else True

filterOutSublists :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
filterOutSublists (n1:n2:ns) = filter subList $ n1 n2 ++ filterOutSublists(n2:ns)

Comment: What if the are not sublists of each other, for example what about `L = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]`?

Comment: XY problem? Perhaps don't generate these short lists in the first place.

Comment: If you have an update, please [edit] your question, comments are not a good place to put Haskell code in.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood problem right, the solution can be like below:

```
import Data.List                                                               

-- Get only if element is not subsequence of any other x element                                                                             
filterOutSublists x = filter (not . (isSub)) x                                 
  where
    -- Check if given element is subsequence of any of x element                                                                     
    isSub y = foldl (\acc y' -> acc || (y `elem` (init $ subsequences y'))) False x
```

But this solution has very bad O(n) complexity, so it is useless for long lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concat` to flatten the sublists, then, since you want to get rid of the duplicates, you can use `Data.Set` to convert it to a set and back again to a list-

```hs
import qualified Data.Set as Set
f = (:[]) . Set.toList . Set.fromList . concat
```

### Output

```hs
λ> f [[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]]
[[1,2,3,4]]
λ> f [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
[[1,2,3,4]]
```

Note that the final `(:[])` is just there to put the final result inside a surrounding list, which is what you have shown in your example - though I don't quite know what even is the point of that.

If you want the results to be just one list instead of a list surrounded by another list, remove the `(:[])` composition.